# Save date with DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I save DD/MM/YYYY format into mongodb database in date type?

After saving it into mongodb, when I retrieved, how can I convert it back to DD/MM/YYYY?

I am using Mongoose.

Comment: You could save it as string

Comment: @Disposer: but you shouldn't – no date range queries on strings, comparisons get more expensive and it has no advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to store dates in mongodb is store them by using native [javascript date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
They allows you to use some useful methods (comparison, map reduce, ...) in mongodb natively.
Then, you can easily get formatted date by using mongoose `virtuals`, e.x.:

```
// describe your schema    
var schema = new Schema({
  time: Date
}, {
  toObject: { getters: true }
});

// schema.formatted_time -> DD/MM/YYYY
schema.virtual('formatted_time').get(function() {
  var date = new Date(this.time);
  return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
});
```